# Google 2 Factor Authentication with Angular and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am looking for API and Example that can help me to build two-factor authentication of my website for the server as well as the front side.
I want to build something like this, http://ngtfaweb.azurewebsites.net/#/home

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Passport Js](http://www.passportjs.org/) if you are using node js as backend or you could use services like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) which are one step solution for multiple Oauth.

Comment: yeh I know about that can you refer any other links if you have

Comment: follow the steps in this [page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2) and you should be great if you are using nodejs as backend

Comment: http://ngtfaweb.azurewebsites.net/#/home, I want to make something like this, is it possible?

Comment: For local Auth read through [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/)

Comment: i am looking for something like when user selects the 2facetor Auth from my website. i want to show one QR code and by Scanning it with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en this app he will generate OTP every 30 seconds.

and while user makes any transaction i want to ask for OTP and authenticate for payment.

Comment: I think [this](https://auth0.com/blog/from-theory-to-practice-adding-two-factor-to-node-dot-js/) will help you