# Node JS API Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication

I'm new to NodeJS and developing an API using it,
I want the API to be authenticated with an API token method (only people with a token stored in DB, created through a specific encryption should be able to access the API resource.)

I'm using an SQL server, NodeJS, and the Express framework.

Please guide me in what I should use to authenticate the API request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this should be helpfull (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552680/google-2-factor-authentication-with-angular-and-nodejs/51552875?noredirect=1#comment90075492_51552875)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) with `JwtStrategy`. This is the idea:

**mypassport.js**

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: 'yourSecret'
};

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (payload, done) => {
    const user = findUserById(payload.id);
    if (!user) {
        return done('user not exists', null);
    }
    return done(null, user);
}));
```

**server.js** (using express)

```
require('./mypassport'); // <- initialize passport strategies

//you could also use passport with local strategy for this
app.post('login', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.query.username;
    const password = req.query.password;
    if (validLogin(username, password)) {
        const user = findUserByUsername(username);
        const jwt = createTokenWithSecret(user, 'yourSecret'); // You can use jwt-simple for this
        res.json({ token: jwt });
    } else {
        //send unauthorized
    }
});

const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('jwt');
app.get('/something', requireLogin, (req, res) => {

    //here, user is authenticated and available in 'req.user'

});
```

First, you must login with `POST /login { username: 'john', password: '1234' }`. That will return a JSON with the jwt token like this:

```
{ token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c' }
```

In subsequent requests, you must send a header `Authorization` with value: `Bearer {token}` so `passportjs` and `JwtStrategy` can authorize the request.

Hope it helps!

NOTE: I have not tested code above, it just shows the approach.

Answer (score 0):

For API Authenication use [Passport JS](http://www.passportjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json web token (jwt) for API authorization. There are node modules available which provides authentication functionality and you can simply use.

Please have a look at this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52?gi=89f3f4d89dfd